# left() takes exactly one argument, 2 given, but I only give 1?

Tags: python, function, arguments

```
def executor(com, rule):
for element in rule.start:
    if element[0] == 'fd':
        com.forward
    elif element[0] == 'bk':
        com.backward
    elif element[0] == 'rt':
        com.right(element[1])
    elif element[0] == 'lt':
        print element[1]
        com.left(60)
    elif element[0] == 'scale':
        com.scale = com.scale * float(element[1])
executor(com, rule)
```

Okay so this is my function, which takes 2 arguments, and I call it with 2 arguments. It works. It's the com.left(60) part, that doesn't work.

```
class Command():
empty = []
count = 0
diction = {}
scale = 7
forward = fd(bob, float(rule.length)*scale)
backward = bk(bob, float(rule.length) * scale)
def right(angle):
    rt(bob, int(angle))
def left(angle):
    lt(bob, int(angle))
com = Command()
```

This is my class. As you can see, right and left is almost exactly identical, but left doesn't work for some reason. I want to call com.left with element[1] as with the right function, but it says the same (elemtent[1] is 60).

I tried called it with 2 arguments, but then I get a **trunc** error, which I also don't know what is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a self parameter to your left and right functions. This will allow those functions to act on instances of your command class.

```
def right(self, angle):
    rt(bob, int(angle))
def left(self, angle):
    lt(bob, int(angle))
```

Whenever your write `com.something()`, the `com` object instance is passed to the function as an implicit parameter.